# Quick Action Button for Junction Object Dynamic Related List

Tags: lightning-app-builder

On the Case record Page in App Builder, I have added a Dynamic Related List - Single to the page. The object for this Related List is a Junction Object between Case and a Custom Object ( lets call it junction__c). I have also created on this Junction Object a Record Quick Action for a custom LWC. Why can I not add this as an Action on the Junction__c Related List on the case page? The only options are New and Change Owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom actions are not available on dynamic related lists, custom buttons are. [Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components.htm&type=5):

> You can add standard actions, **custom buttons**, and Create a Record and Update a Record quick actions on dynamic related lists. Quick actions are available as mass actions on the related list.

Please note that [mass actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_customization_general_related_list_quick_actions.htm&release=244&type=5) are in beta.

You could create a custom button (Object Manager > Your Object > New Button or Link) with Display Type equals to List Button, then it will shows up as an action on your dynamic related lists, but of course it isn't a replacement for an LWC quick action.

Comment: Thank you. :facepalm: